# Posting variable within a hidden div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dropdown in my form with a 'Yes' or 'No' option, if the user selects 'No' a hidden Div appears with a text box for the user to fill in. If the user clicks 'Yes' they just move on to the next question. I'm getting an undefined index error on the questions the user selects 'Yes' where the hidden div doesn't show.

Here is my index.php which contains the form and hidden div

```
<form id="newForm" action="" method="post">
    <div id="hiddenQuestion1">
        <strong>1. Are the Team Players Wearing Gloves for the correct procedure?</strong> 
        <select id="questions1" name="question1" onchange="showfield1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br><div id="div1"></div><br>
    <!--Function to display text box if users selects no-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield1(name){
    if(name=='No')
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Please provide a reason: <input type="text" id="reason1" name="reason1" size="43" /> Add attachment (Optional): <input type="file" id="attachmentFile1" name="attachmentFile1" class="InputBox">';
    else 
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
</script>

    <div id="hiddenQuestion2" style="display:none">
        <strong>2. Are Team Players using the ESD station and signing daily sheet?</strong> 
        <select id="questions2" name="question2" onchange="showfield2(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br><div id="div2"></div><br>
<!--Function to display text box if users selects no-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield2(name){
    if(name=='No')
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='Please provide a reason: <input type="text" id="reason2" name="reason2" size="43" /> Add attachment (Optional): <input type="file" id="attachmentFile2" name="attachmentFile2" class="InputBox">';
    else 
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';
}
</script>
```

Here is my post.php page

```
$reason1 = $_POST['reason1'];
$attachment1 = $_FILES['attachmentFile1']["name"];
$question2 = $_POST['question2'];
if($question2 ==''){
    $data['error'] = "question 2 missing";
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
$reason2 = $_POST['reason2'];
$attachment2 = $_FILES['attachmentFile2']["name"];
$question3 = $_POST['question3'];
if($question3 ==''){
    $data['error'] = "question 3 missing";
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
```

So if the user selects 'Yes' to question 1, and 'No' to question 2, I get the error 'Undefined index: reason2' in the post.php page as per below...

```
"<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: reason1 in 
<b>D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SMT_24_Point_Check\newAudit.php</b> on line <b>17</b> 
<br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: attachmentFile1 in 
<b>D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SMT_24_Point_Check\newAudit.php</b> on line <b>18</b> 
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: show us the full error

Comment: just edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the 'Undefined index' error because if the answer is 'no', you don't even generate the input in your DOM, therefore that post variable won't exist. A quick fix for this would be the following:

Instead of lines like:

```
$reason2 = $_POST['reason2'];
```

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['reason2'])) {
    $reason2 = $_POST['reason2'];
} else {
    $reason2 = '';
}
```

Or the same thing, but in a shorter and more elegant fashion:

```
$reason2 = ($_POST['reason2']) ? $_POST['reason2'] : ''
```

Another solution for this would be always including the HTML input, but hide it initially with `display: none;` - then make it visible depending on the user's answer. This way, `$_POST['reason2']` will always exist, and be empty if it's unset.

Comment: For some more syntactic sugar (PHP 7): `$reason2 = $_POST['reason2'] ?? ''`

Answer (score 4):

This is what happen when you select **Yes** for the **option 1** there is no value for hidden field `reason1`  So that you can do something like this in post.php

Fist check with `isset()` function is `reason1` has a value or not like this

```
if(isset($_POST['reason1'])) {
    $reason1 = $_POST['reason1'];
} else {
    $reason1 = 0; `//Better to pass a value in here for future refernces`
}
```

Then when you select `No` to **option2** and if you **leave it empty**(*I can see that you have written i as optional*) So that it also dosent have a value.So that you can do the same this what did for `$reason1` like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['attachmentFile1'])) {
        $attachmentFile1= $_POST['attachmentFile1'];
    } else {
        $attachmentFile1= 0; `//Better to pass a value in here for future refernces`
    }
```

Thanks